# SQL How to Join 2 tables so that only matching records from Table 2 are shown

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

In MS Access, I am trying to do a search for matched records so that I only see records from Table 1 that have a match in table 2. No matter what I try, I end up getting way more records in my result set than Table 1 has to begin with. I've tried inner join, left join... I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I only want the records from Table 1 where there is a match in table 2.

Table 1 has 294,037 records

When I run:

```
Select Table1.Key
From Table1
Inner Join Table2
On Table1.Key = Table.Key;
```

My result set has 4,428,853 records.

Comment: An inner join should be the correct type of join.  The only thing I can think of is that you have a one-to-many relationship between table1 and table2.  For example, for a given key in table1 there could be more than one row that matches that in table two.  Since your output is only the table1.key column, you could try adding distinct to your query.

Comment: Should `Table.Key` be `Table2.Key`?

Comment: add a where clause for a specific record from table 1.  Now that you know that key use it to select records from table2.  Note you likely have Many records for that one Foreign Key. So which record do you want from table 2 when this occurs?  What you're getting now is normal behavior in a 1-to-Many relationship

Answer (score 3):

If you want only the matched records from Table1 with that of table2 then use `exists` or `in` clause to get the desired output. Below is the same to get your output

```
Select T1.Key From Table1 T1 where 
exists (select 1 from Table2 T2 where T1.Key = T2.Key);
```

Comment: This would work, but it is rather inefficient.  A DISTINCT or GROUP BY query would probably be better so that access does not need to execute the subquery for every record in Table1.  But even before this solution is considered, the asker needs to understand the table and data... whether the relationship should be one-to-many or if there are unexpected duplicate entries in Table2, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want NULL values for rows where there is a row on the right side, but no matching row on the left side (that would be a `RIGHT JOIN`), it sounds like you want an 'INNER JOIN'.  However, if the `JOIN` criteria match more than one row, you'll get more than one row in the results.  Here's how it works:

1. Find the stuff on the left side (the table specified before `INNER JOIN` in the query),
2. Find the stuff on the right side (the table specified after `INNER JOIN` in the query),
3. Next, match up rows from each side according to the specified criteria (specified after `ON`),
4. If, for *one* matching row on the left side, there is *one* matching row from the right side, put the column values from the left row with the column values from the right table into a row in the result
5. If there is *more than one* matching row on either side, make a copy of every row from each side such that the results have every possible matching combination, and put them into the result.

If a data from single row from either side is showing in the results more than once, it can only be because the criteria used for the `JOIN` (the conditions after the `ON` clause) resulted in more than one row on one side matching one or more rows on the other side.

For example, if I have the following two tables:

```
Table1 | Key | Value 
------ | --- | -----
       |  1  |    A1
       |  1  |    A2
       |  2  |    B
       |  3  |    C
       |  5  |    E


Table2 | Key | Value 
------ | --- | -----
       |  1  |    Z
       |  2  |    Y
       |  3  |    X1
       |  3  |    X2
       |  4  |    W
```

The following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 first 
RIGHT JOIN Table2 second ON first.Key=second.Key
```

would return the following results:

```
Table2 | Key | Value | Key | Value 
------ | --- | ----- | --- | -----
       |  1  |    A1 |  1  |    Z
       |  1  |    A2 |  1  |    Z
       |  2  |    B  |  2  |    Y
       |  3  |    C  |  3  |    X1
       |  3  |    C  |  3  |    X2
       |NULL |  NULL |  4  |    W
```

Notice that the 1,Z row from Table2 appears twice in the results and the 3,C row from A also appears twice.  4,W appears because it's a `RIGHT JOIN`.  A `LEFT JOIN` would have put 5,E in the results, and an `INNER JOIN` (or just plain `JOIN`) would have neither of those rows.  An `OUTER JOIN` would include both of those rows.

If Table2 had two entries with Key 1 (let's say Z1 and Z2), there would have been FOUR results with a Key of 1 (one with A1,Z1, one with A2,Z1, one with A1,Z2, and one with A2,Z2).  This is where things really balloon, and from your numbers, it looks like you probably have several key values where this is the case.

If the values in Table1 and Table2 all had the same key values, the result set would contain every possible combination of values, so the number of rows in the result set would be the number of rows in Table1 *times* the number of rows in Table2.

Restrictions found in the `WHERE` clause may also trim result rows that don't match all of the criteria specified there.

For an `INNER JOIN`, having more rows in the result set than the smaller of the source tables can't happen unless there are multiple matches in step 4 above.  If you want to make sure there is only one match, you must have unique keys (keys where there can only be one row with any given key) for both tables, you must alter the `ON` criteria to limit matches to one row, or you must filter one side of the `JOIN` such that it only has the rows that you want to join.